# Dynamically Select Column Based on a Bytefield

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To create a set of Items, we compare all items to find those which have 'Something' in common.

This little 'Something' is defined by a table that stores ColumnName and a ByteValue. In order to know which Column we need to make a comparison.

As a picture often says more than words, here is a basic sketch.

**Table Parameter that stores the ByteField signification:**

In Green and example of Column combination use as comparator, giving us `71`  as Comparator.

[image: Table Parameter that store the ByteField Signification]

**Table data :**
[image]

How to build a query returning a list of Data Id, taking as input a Data Id as base for comparison and a predefined combination of Column? Here `71`.

For this example lets say we look for Set item based on DataID=1 and Byte=71. The expected result is : `1, 4, 5`.

Here is [a sample of the database](http://pastebin.com/N3fbVwkh).

And because i was "bitten once", I'm not asking you to do my job. I am handling it with some code but I would love to see how to do that in T-SQL. That's why I provided a sample table.

Comment: This is a *very* arcane data structure.  Why not identify the conditions directly by using column names?

Comment: Im not sure i get it but in fact this is for the sake of exemple. I have in fact 23 Column that can be use in comparaison. Depending of the user not on the product. 15 combinaison are commonly used but there is in fact many other.

Comment: . . Why would you use bit fiddling to define column names, when SQL provides a very reasonable alternative:  the column names themselves?

Comment: Gordon ever experienced with an old badabase that is the core of the system.. with questionable choice.. and No Strong link between table ? Welcom in my world.

Comment: To answer your question i find bitfield quite a good choice here. I mean bitfield are made for this. What is your option storing a string, concatenation of all the column ... or storing column n acessing it by index, i mean no one gonna add a column in the 5th position. Storing column name in a table and acessing by the the id and getting the Id thats basically a bitfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the columns of table "Data" and the values defined in column "Parameter".

---

With static SQL you have to know the names of the columns in advance.

```
declare @compactor  int = 71
        ,@DataID    int = 1

select        *
from
      ( select  t.*
                ,min (case "ID" when @DataID then 'Y' end) over (partition by rnk) as is_requested_row
        from   ( select t.*
                        , rank () over
                            (
                                order by  case when @compactor / power(2,0) % 2 = 1 then "Color" end
                                         ,case when @compactor / power(2,1) % 2 = 1 then "Type" end
                                         ,case when @compactor / power(2,2) % 2 = 1 then "Type2" end
                                         ,case when @compactor / power(2,3) % 2 = 1 then "Name" end
                                         ,case when @compactor / power(2,4) % 2 = 1 then "Sci_name"   end
                                         -- ,case when @compactor / power(2,5) % 2 = 1 then "Alias"     end
                                         ,case when @compactor / power(2,6) % 2 = 1 then "Version"  end
                                         -- ,case when @compactor / power(2,7) % 2 = 1 then "Firmware"  end
                                         -- ,case when @compactor / power(2,8) % 2 = 1 then "Brand"     end
                                         -- ,case when @compactor / power(2,9) % 2 = 1 then "Avaidable" end
                            )   as rnk
                  from   "Data" as t
                ) t
        ) t
where is_requested_row = 'Y'
order by    "ID" ;
```

Comment: miss match where ?

Comment: "Alias", "Firmware" and "Avaidable" are defined in the "Parameter" table but they are not columns in the "Data" table

Comment: Thats why i add "not all displayed" comment  because i know i wasn't going to select them in the exemple.  but i see what i mean I simplified data to make the pic look ok. but if some one use my stample it could cause error. Yeah my bad . I will update sql script.

Comment: Take my +1 as a well-deserved reward. I think i must wait for a dynamics solution before choosing a winner .. yes am picky .

Comment: @PierreLebon, thanks. If I remember correctly SQL Server's dynamic SQL, it can't be embedded inside a query. So the solution you are looking for might be a procedure but not a query.

Comment: @pierreLebon, SQL SERVER 2008 doesn't support analytics functions.

Comment: Yeah am crying .. we are plannign to get 2014 in 2 years...
I will edit my Question and Your answer to underline the fact that its SQLServeur 2014 related.

Comment: @PierreLebon, 2008 was 8 years ago. Just saying :-)

Comment: What if i tell you We are on 2005 compatible mode 2000 and 2008 is going to come in the begining of next years..

Comment: @PierreLebon, Wow. I would rather work with Excel. Man, this is really sad.  The best practice as I see it is to get the newest version as soon as the first service pack is out and never, never, never open a lag of more than one version behind.